# In PHP what is the most efficient way to create two array items which have exactly the same value?

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing a code review with a colleague and we'd like to know the most efficient way to create an array which has 2 items in it which are both the same string.

If we declare an array and a string like this:

```
$args = [];
$param = "a string";
```

And we want the result:

```
print_r($args); //Array([0] => "a string" [1] => "a string")
```

The original code we had was:

```
array_push($args, $param);
array_push($args, $param);
```

We recognised that this may be better:

```
array_push($args, $param, $param);
```

But is there a quicker or more elegant way?

Also: Is this a completely trivial question? I tried to time the operation with `microtime()` and I'm not able to get a measurement - but maybe I'm doing something wrong!

---

The wider context of the problem is that `$args` is an array of parameters that will be passed into an SQL query. We're working in wordpress and a simplified version of the query is:

```
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT term_taxonomy_id AS 'instrument_category_id_to_show'
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE object_id IN(
        SELECT posts.ID
        FROM wp_posts posts
        JOIN wp_term_relationships term_relationships
        ON posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id
        WHERE (posts.post_content like %s OR posts.post_title like %s)
    )

    AND term_taxonomy_id IN (1,2,3)
";

$sql = $wpdb->prepare($query,$args);
```

Comment: Show your query building too, there could be a way to save you time depending on what you're using.

Comment: Also to consider is `$args[] = $param; $args[] = $param;` does the same thing too ;) ... but is it faster?

Comment: If the array is empty to begin with, why not just do `$args = [$param, $param]`.  I can't imagine any of the other solutions being faster.

Comment: For something that really won't break the bank in performance, I always opt for "what looks better in the code" (from a visual standpoint, readability). But thats the artist in me =p

Comment: AymDev - done, thanks. @IncredibleHat, Devon - yes I meant to articulate - any other possibilities would be welcomed! Thanks for confirming our thoughts on the readability being perhaps the most important thing!

Comment: @AndrewChart I posted an answer, bypassing your issue ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do it with `array_fill`:

```
$args = array_fill(0, 2, $param);
```

I don't know if this is better than your `array_push` version by your standards.

> Is this a completely trivial question?

Yes. Completely trivial. If the difference between any two options is more than a thousandth of your network latency, I'd be astonished.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that:

```
$args[]= $param;
$args[]= $param; //two times

//------------ or ------------------

$args = [0=>$param, 1=>$param];

//------------ or -----------------

$args = [$param, $param];
```

As you said, with array_push or different functions... but honestly... there is no difference between this ways to do it. The result will be the same in more or less the same execution time.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to insert data multiple time. You are using **PDO**, you can prepare your query with the semicolon syntax ([named parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples)):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare(
    'SELECT field
    FROM table
    WHERE
        field_a = :user_input
        AND field_b = :user_input
        AND field_c LIKE :input_b'
);
```

Then sending an associative array to the [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method without having to duplicate the arguments:

```
$query->execute([
    'user_input' => $param,
    'input_b'    => '%' . $param . '%'
]);
```